# Do phrases "Yes, it did not." and "No, it did not." have different meanings?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Let say the question is:

> So this ended up not working?

What is the proper way to say, this indeed not work?

These two seem fine to me:

> Yes, it did not.

or

> No, it did not.

Are they both right? Or does one of them have different meaning. Is there any difference between the two phrases?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply delete the 'it did not' part here.

```
So this ended up not working?
```

What is the right answer?

```
Yes
```

or

```
No
```

With the 'Yes', you are automatically agreeing with the person asking the question, on the other hand, with the 'No', you are disagreeing with him/her and telling him/her that it ended up working.